# Fermion Lagrangian with linear momentum versus quadratic momentum

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, operators, field-theory, fermions

$$
L = \bar{\psi} (\gamma^\mu (p_\mu -A_\mu)- m)\psi
\tag{1}
$$
$$
L = \bar{\psi} ((\gamma^\mu( p_\mu-A_\mu))^2 - m^2)\psi
\tag{2}
$$

Is there a difference between the two Lagragians in equations 1 and 2? I think they give the same equations of motion, but I am unsure if they give the same field operators in Quantum Field theory.

They mostly give the same equations of motion. There is a subtle difference; The quadratic equation (2) yields the existence of a second solution not found in the linear equation (1). As far as I am aware there is no way to experimentally distinguish between Dirac and Klein-Gordon if no electromagnetic interaction is imposed. Once you impose an electromagnetic interaction you can observe both theoretically and experimentally how the particle couples to the electromagnetic field.

Comment: Notice that what you call $p_{\mu}$ in the above must be the derivative $\partial_{\mu}$. Moreover: *"I think they give the same equations of motion..."*: well, instead, you may just want to calculate and find out. Do they give the same equations of motion for the fields? This said, the field operators are **not** given by the Lagrangian: they exist already there and the Lagrangian is just a function thereof (the quantisation happening via path integral).

Comment: And now (v3) we are back to $D^\mu$ but the Lagrangians still do not give the same equations of motion.

Answer (score 1):

They do not give the same equation of motion. The upper one is well known and gives the Dirac equation, the lower one gives the Klein-Gordon equation (for four independent complex fields).

Note that $\gamma_0$ is diagonal, $\bar \psi = \psi^\dagger\gamma^0$ and (using the commutativity of momentum components):
$$ (\gamma^\mu p_\mu)^2 = \gamma^\mu p_\mu \gamma^\nu p_\nu = \frac 1 2 (\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu + \gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu) p_\mu p_\nu = \frac 1 2 \{\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu\} p_\mu p_\nu = \eta^{\mu\nu}p_\mu p_\nu = p^\mu p_\mu.$$
That means, that we have an action, just containg a sum of four terms of the form ($\psi = (\phi_0, \ldots, \phi_3)^T$)
$$ \pm \phi_i^* (\Box - m^2) \phi_i. $$

While all solutions of the second equation of motion are solutions of the first one (which is obvious from the factoring $(\gamma^\mu p_\mu)^2 - m^2 = (\gamma^\mu p_\mu + m)(\gamma^\mu p_\mu - m)$, the reverse is not true.

So if you quantize the second Lagrangian in field theory, I would guess, you will run into trouble if you try to make the variable anti-commute, as the Lagrangian corresponds to a Bosonic theory.

Comment: Although this is usually implicit, it may be worth noticing that in order to identify $p_{\mu}$ with the derivative one has to assume that the solutions have to be able to be expanded in Fourier series (which is true in the case at hand, being the equations linear, so to speak). Taking derivatives of $e^{ipx}$ one gets $p_{\mu}$ replacing the derivatives (but then the field appearing is no more the original field, rather its Fourier coefficients).

Comment: They mostly give the same equations of motion. There is a subtle difference; The quadratic equation (2) yields the existence of a second solution not found in the linear equation (1). As far as I am aware there is no way to experimentally distinguish between Dirac and Klein-Gordon if no electromagnetic interaction is imposed. Once you impose an electromagnetic interaction you can observe both theoretically and experimentally how the particle couples to the electromagnetic field.

Comment: @linuxfreebird *"They mostly give the same equations"*: if the equations are different, they are different; being "mostly" the same is still a different equation.

Answer (score 1):

Why they give the same equations of motion? 
From the first one Lagrangian, we get
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \bar\psi}=(\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}-m)\psi=0,\tag{1}$$
while from the second we obtain
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial\bar\psi}=(\gamma^{\{\mu}\gamma^{\nu\}}p_{\mu}p_{\nu}-m^2)\bar\psi=(p^2-m^2)\psi=0.\tag{2}$$
From eq.(1) we can obtain eq.(2), but not vice versa. Eq.(1) implies that $\psi$ is a spinor while eq.(2) is the Klein-Gordon equation.

Comment: They mostly give the same equations of motion. There is a subtle difference; The quadratic equation (2) yields the existence of a second solution not found in the linear equation (1). As far as I am aware there is no way to experimentally distinguish between Dirac and Klein-Gordon if no electromagnetic interaction is imposed. Once you impose an electromagnetic interaction you can observe both theoretically and experimentally how the particle couples to the electromagnetic field.

Comment: @linuxfreebird Well, there is no way to distinguish *any* interaction without a coupling. Whatever you measure is always a result of a coupling with some other fields, you never measure free fields (by definition of measurement).